# SQL - Select highest value when data across 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, greatest-n-per-group

I have 3 tables:

1. `Person` (with a column `PersonKey`)
2. `Telephone` (with columns `Tel_NumberKey`, `Tel_Number`, `Tel_NumberType` e.g. 1=home, 2=mobile)
3. `xref_Person+Telephone` (columns `PersonKey`, `Tel_NumberKey`, `CreatedDate`, `ModifiedDate`)

I'm looking to get the most recent (e.g. the highest `Tel_NumberKey`) from the `xref_Person+Telephone` for each `Person` and use that `Tel_NumberKey` to get the actual `Tel_Number` from the `Telephone` table.

The problem I am having is that I keep getting duplicates for the same `Tel_NumberKey`. I also need to be sure I get both the home and mobile from the `Telephone` table, which I've been looking to do via 2 individual joins for each `Tel_NumberType` - again getting duplicates.

Been trying the following but to no avail:

```
-- For HOME
SELECT 
    p.PersonKey, pn.Phone_Number, pn.Tel_NumberKey
FROM 
    Persons AS p 
INNER JOIN 
    xref_Person+Telephone AS x ON p.PersonKey = x.PersonKey
INNER JOIN 
    Telephone AS pn ON x.Tel_NumberKey = pn.Tel_NumberKey
WHERE 
    pn.Tel_NumberType = 1 -- e.g. Home phone number
    AND pn.Tel_NumberKey = (SELECT MAX(pn1.Tel_NumberKey) AS Tel_NumberKey
                            FROM Person AS p1  
                            INNER JOIN xref_Person+Telephone AS x1 ON p1.PersonKey = x1.PersonKey
                            INNER JOIN Telephone AS pn1 ON x1.Tel_NumberKey = pn1.Tel_NumberKey
                            WHERE pn1.Tel_NumberType = 1
                              AND p1.PersonKey = p.PersonKey
                              AND pn1.Tel_Number = pn.Tel_Number)
ORDER BY 
    p.PersonKey
```

And have been looking over the following links but again keep getting duplicates.

[SQL select max(date) and corresponding value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942306/sql-select-maxdate-and-corresponding-value)

[How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql)

[SQL Server: SELECT only the rows with MAX(DATE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118170/sql-server-select-only-the-rows-with-maxdate)

Am sure this must be possible but been at this a couple of days and can't believe its that difficult to get the most recent / highest value when referencing 3 tables. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just for reference try using oracle ANALYTICAL Functions

Comment: Tag the dbms used, the answer may be product specific.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using MS SSMS 2012

Answer (score 2):

```
select * 
from 
( SELECT p.PersonKey, pn.Phone_Number, pn.Tel_NumberKey 
       , row_number() over (partition by p.PersonKey, pn.Phone_Number order by pn.Tel_NumberKey desc) rn
  FROM 
      Persons AS p 
  INNER JOIN 
      xref_Person+Telephone AS x ON p.PersonKey = x.PersonKey
  INNER JOIN 
      Telephone AS pn ON x.Tel_NumberKey = pn.Tel_NumberKey
  WHERE 
      pn.Tel_NumberType = 1 
) tt 
where tt.rn = 1  
ORDER BY 
    tt.PersonKey
```

Comment: will have a go of this and let you know how i get on - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use max() function and then you have to order by rownum in descending order like.

```
select  f.empno 
from(select max(empno) empno from emp e 
group by rownum)f
order by rownum desc
```

It will give you all employees having highest employee number to lowest employee number. Now implement it with your case then let me know.